# POSTing data return error instead of success

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and I am trying to send my data to Spring-MVC Controller using AJAX, on button click. I have written this code (given below) but I am getting error instead of success. please tell what can be the issue?

**AJAX:**

```
function add() {
                var name   = $('#name').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/addUser",
                    data : name,
                    type : "POST",
                    async: false,
                    success : function(response) {
                        alert( response );
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert("error....");
                    }
                });
            }
```

**JAVA**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("UserTest") String name) {
      //task
      return name;
   }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: error alert is being popped-up. there is no error on console.

Comment: If you included teh `jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown` parameters in your error function, you would have access to more information.

Comment: Instead of `success : function(response) {` try `success : function(data) {`

Comment: `data : {"name":name},`?